# Pandoc `lang` option makes font ugly

Tags: fonts, latex, pandoc, cyrillic

I am trying to learn `pandoc`. I used `latex` before because I always deal with formulas, code. Here is the simple document I compile to pdf:

````
---
title: Test
...

# Test!

This is a test of *pandoc*.

- list one
- list two
- $E=mc^2$
- На русском

Горит костер рябины красной.

$$
A = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx
$$

```python
class ClassName(object):
    """docstring for ClassName (Кириллица?)"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__() # English comment
        self.arg = arg # Кириллический комментарий

```
````

I've tried two different commands to produce pdf:

1. `pandoc test1.md -o test1.pdf`
2. `pandoc -V lang=ru-RU -o test1-2.pdf test1.md`

The first command failed rendering for cyrillic symbols. Moreover, I always write non-English documents, so I need documents to be generated with captions written in russian. I used `lang` property to do it as `pandoc` documentation suggests. Now, cyrillic symbols render correct but if you look at the screenshot a couple of seconds you can see that font looks much uglier than before. Espesially code.

What is going on and how to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: probably it chose a different font now... you can try `pandoc -s -o output.tex` to see the LaTeX pandoc generates. Then you can fix it by e.g. setting the right `mainfont`, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex

Comment: @mb21 yes you are right. The problem was `pandoc` set Latin Modern font as default font. It does not have cyrillic glyphs. I've changed pdf-engine to `xelatex` and set font to DejaVu Serif. Now it works fine for text and code but I still have issues with math, because pandoc ignores `-V mathfont="Some Math Font"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it difficult to set-up fonts for Latin, Cyrillic, Math and code blocks in a consistent way with the interface offered by `pandoc`. The best compromise I found was:

- Set `lang` equal to `en` and mark-up Russian parts explicitly.
- Use XITS fonts for normal text and math
- Use a fixed width font that covers Cyrillic, e.g. Liberation Mono
- Process with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

All combined:

````
---
title: Test
mainfont: XITS
monofont: Liberation Mono
mathfont: XITS Math
lang: en
---

# Test!

This is a test of *pandoc*.

- list one
- list two
- $E=mc^2$
- [На русском]{.class lang="ru-RU"}

::::: {.class lang="ru-RU"}

Горит костер рябины красной.

:::::


$$
A = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx
$$


```python
class ClassName(object):
    """docstring for ClassName (Кириллица?)"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__() # English comment
        self.arg = arg # Кириллический комментарий

```
````

Result of `pandoc cyr.md --pdf-engine=lualatex  -o cyr.pdf`:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am doing smth wrong but it seems that your solution face the same problem with math font: If you use smth like this in equation: `$k_Б = 1,381 \cdot 10^{-23}$` than underscored "Б" wont render. Moreover, compiler say this: `[WARNING] Missing character: There is no Б (U+0411) in font lmmi10!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no Б (U+0411) in font lmmi7!`. It looks like XITS math did not set as math font.

Comment: @danielleontiev If I remove `mathfont: XITS Math` I get a visibly different result. So I am positive that for me the mathfont is set-up correctly. I would use `$k_\text{Б} = 1,381 \cdot 10^{-23}$` since the "Б" is probably meant as abbreviation of "Boltzmann" (in Cyrillic transliteration). And if it is not a mathematical variable, the surrounding text font should be used. Things get more difficult if you want to use Cyrillic letters for variables. I know no font that is set-up for that.